# Rails - add a value to a combobox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a combobox and that present all the values (1 to many) of my object.
I have implemnted a text field with ajax that retrieves values from the DB using ajax.
Now, want to a add a button that inserts the data from the textfield to the combobox.
I than would like that it would be saved only when user choose to.

I am having troubles implementing the add button that adds the data only on the client side and waits untill the user clicks on save.

Any suggestions? 
Rails cast maybe ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association

The railscast above implements what you want with autocomplete feature, watch it fully, you will be good to go, I hope.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I already watched it . Thats how I implemented the autocomplete. I now seek to implement an add feature as described above. From the Textfield to the combobox. on the client side.